# ASUS RT-N18U router - firmware restore trouble

Tags: router, wireless-router, troubleshooting, restore, firmware

I have an ASUS RT-N18U router, which I need to have the original firmware restored.

I follow the instructions of this website:

https://byndthwll.com/2016/05/04/revert-back-to-stock-firmware-on-asus-rt-n18u/

I executed steps 1-5 successfully, but at step 6 the router is not recognized by the Asus Firmware Restoration Utility. It counts until 30 seconds, then stops with the message, that can not find wireless router in restoration mode.

Any idea how to recover the router and flash back the original firmware?

**EDIT1:**

Using firmware:
AdvancedTomato Version 3.4-140 AIO

https://advancedtomato.com/downloads/router/rt-n18u

Thanks!

Comment: What firmware is currently installed?

Comment: Using Advanced Tomato firmware. See details in edited OP.

Comment: Are you sure you have the router in recovery mode ?  (IE power flashing very slow ?)

Comment: Yes, power is flashing very slow (about every 25-30 seconds on-off). But the utility is not recognizing.